# How to use JavaScript file in Angular2 component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, webpack

I've to embed a widget, which a executing on load. In a normal html page, I would put the script:

```
<script src="rectangleDrawing.js"></script>
```

And then I would put a `div` as a placeholder:

```
<div name="rectangle></div>
```

The problem is now that I can't just put the `script` into the template, because it will be removed. Also the `rectangleDrawing.js`, is not exporting itself as a module.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

- Put the `<script>` inside index.html page
- Put the `<div..` markup inside a component template

Probably that script will expose some global variables that you can use inside your component, it depends what's inside and how it works...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was just doing a little more research. I'm using webpack. Could I use a script-loader and load the script only into the component? Just to avoid to have it global and only accessible for this component.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not the most elegant option, but it works. Just put this into you Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadScript();
}

private loadScript(): void {
    const node = document.createElement('script');
    node.src = 'yourScript.js';
    node.type = 'text/javascript';
    node.async = true;
    node.charset = 'utf-8';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
}
```