# Angular 2 import a javascript (untyped) file

Tags: javascript, file, angular, import

I tried to reformulate one of my previous question as nobody seems to have understood what I was trying to achieve. Must be my bad English...

I have an un-typed js file that I need to import/use in an angular 2 component.

I cannot use npm install as the library in question does not have a NPM installation: PLYLoader.js It uses THREE JS.

I have successfully imported THREE js as it has a npm install and it is available and working in my component.

There is not clear example out there that explains in detail how and where to import a JS file into angular 2. Please note is a JS not a TS.

This is driving me mad, any help will be very much appreciated.

Ciao. Dino

Comment: Does you PLYLoader.js exposes it self as a module?

Comment: This goes out to if you PLYLoader.js is exposing it self like jQuery for example. jQuery eposes itself with the `$` to the document. Does your PLYLoader do that? If so you can add it to your `index.html` and in you component you can do something like: `declare const <your_place_holder> : any;`

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you

Comment: Super! Just copied my comment into the Answers section! ;-)

Comment: This may help you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40436396/how-to-use-javascript-file-in-angular2-component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already explained in the comments, if your `PLYLoader.js` is exposing it self like `jQuery` for example. `jQuery` eposes itself with the `$` to the document. Does your `PLYLoader.js` do that? If so you can add it to your `index.html` and in you component you can do something like: `declare const <your_place_holder> : any;`

Please let me know if you have any further questions.